# Sort text files in bash

Tags: shell

I have a number of text files in the current directory. Each file contains data about a movie.The content of each file will be according to the following format:

```
Movie name

Storyline

Director name

Year of release
```

How can I organize the files according to the name of the directors by a shell script. Movies made by same director will get moved to a folder named after the director. How can I do this by writing shell script?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can read the nth line and also know how to create folder and move files from one folder to another. But for this task, i need to use the filename as variable and run through a loop. And I'm stuck!

Comment: You're not providing enough information. What are the files named? What will they be named after they are sorted? Do you have some code to show what you've done that can be updated or improved to do this? What do you want the files to look like once they are sorted? Will it just be the movie, storyline, directory, year one after the other?

Comment: I have added a text file named "avatar.txt". there will like 20 text files.
Movies created by same director will be moved to a folder named after the director.

Comment: In the sample text, there' no blank line between the directory and year. How strict is your format? Is the director always the 2nd last line?

Comment: Yes, format is always exactly like this.

Answer (score 0):

The rough solution will be

```
for file in *; do
    director=$( some code here depending on requirements clarification )
    mkdir -p "$director"      # quotes are crucial!
                              # -p suppresses errors if dir already exists.
    mv -v "$file" "$director"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the filename of the movie is always the first line, and the Director name is always the next to last. You could do it something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash


MOVIES_DIR=/path/to/your/movies

for FILE in ${MOVIES_DIR}/*.txt; do

    # Movie name will always be the first line
    MOVIE=$(sed '1q;d' "$FILE")

    # Director will always be the next to last line
    DIRECTOR=$(tac "$FILE" | sed '2q;d')

    # Make the director folder
    mkdir -p "${MOVIES_DIR}/${DIRECTOR}"

    # Find inside the `MOVIES_DIR` files with the movie name with any extension
    # That is NOT .txt and moves them to the proper director folder.
    find "${MOVIES_DIR}" -maxdepth 1 -name "${MOVIE}.*" -not -name '*.txt' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' NAME; do
        FILENAME=$(printf '%s\n' "$NAME")
        mv "$FILENAME" "${MOVIES_DIR}/${DIRECTOR}"
    done
done
```

### Edit:

It was my misunderstanding that you wanted to move movies with the same name in the text file into the appropriate director folder. I now see you are intending to move the ***text*** files themselves. I downloaded all the text files from the link you provided, and it successfully sorted all of them into the appropriate folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

MOVIES_DIR=/path/to/your/files

for FILE in ${MOVIES_DIR}/*.txt; do

    # I thought the description was on one line, but it looks like it can span
    # multiple. So get the next to last line instead, since year is only one line. I also changed this in the first script.
    DIRECTOR=$(tac "$FILE" | sed '2q;d')

    DIRECTOR_PATH="$MOVIES_DIR/$DIRECTOR"
    mkdir -p "$DIRECTOR_PATH"

    # Move the current text file to the Director folder.
    mv "$FILE" "$DIRECTOR_PATH"
done
```

The first script should sort all ***movies*** into the director folders, assuming that the text files are in the same directory as the movies.

The second script should sort all ***text*** files into the appropriate director folders.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome solution. but i'm getting errors.

sed: can't read /*.txt  : No such file or directory

Comment: I have like 20 text files each containing data of one movie.

Comment: Did you change the `MOVIES_DIR` variable at the top of the script? It should point to the directory that the text files are in.

Comment: It is also assumed that the movies themselves (with the same name in the first line of the text file) are in the same directory.

Comment: Yeah, directory was modified.
The problem i face is anytime i write command in ubuntu it fails to access space.
If name is "batman" my ubuntu command works but it fails for "batman begins" . I can't fix the space problem.

Comment: Oh, okay. My mistake. I forgot to put double quotes around `$FILE` when calling to sed. I have made an edit to my post. Just change `$FILE` to `"$FILE"` like above, and it should read file names as expected.

Comment: I have made another edit to the end of the script to grab all movies with any extension and move them. That way, inside the text file, it only needs to be "Batman Begins" and not "Batman Begins.mp4". It will now move all copies of "Batman Begins" regardless of extension.

Comment: I had a misunderstanding at first. I thought you wanted to move *movies* with the same name into the folder with the director's name. I apologize. I have edited my post to move the text files themselves into the folders.